# Express 4 route precedence

Tags: node.js, express

Prior to express 4, you could do things like

```
    app.get('/foo/bar', bar);
    app.get('/foo/*', foo);
```

to cause the `bar` middleware to be used when `/foo/bar` is requested and the `foo` middleware when `/foo/baz` is requested. However, in express 4, `/foo/bar` will call the `bar` middleware and the `foo` middleware. Is there a way to achieve the express 3 behavior with express 4?

One way I can think of is to have my second route parameter be `/foo/(?!bar)`, but that seems a little crazy.

Comment: Express will stop after any callback that doesn't call `next` and I don't think that has changed in 4.

Comment: Correct. I oversimplified my statement of the problem from what I actually have. I have another middleware `app.use(baz)` which I want to be used by both. the express 3 way of doing that would be `app.get('/foo/bar', bar, baz)` and `app.get('/foo/*', foo, baz)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your goal is to have bar() called when /foo/bar is passed, else foo() is called. One way to do it is just to use /foo/:value.  In fooHandler(), check if req.params.value === 'bar', then call bar(), else call foo().  This makes the code clearer to read, IMO.

```
app.get('/foo/:value', fooHandler);

:
:

function fooHandler(req, res) {
  if (req.params.value === 'bar') {
    this.bar(req, res);
  } else {
    this.foo(req, res);
  }
}

function bar(req, res) {/* do something */}

function foo(req, res) {/* do something */}
```